# Pulling data from Sybase SQL database using rolling window

Tags: sql, sybase

I wish to pull three years of data from a database but right now I have to specify the dates in a number of sections in my code using a between statement:

```
BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2018-09-30'
```

Since the database only contains valid data from the previous month backwards, I wish to take the end of the last month and go back three years.

I found [this](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/18/sql-server-find-last-day-of-any-month-current-previous-next/) tutorial where the author shows how to do this in SQL server and I've tried to adapt it but my RDBMS is throwing errors in the datediff function

```
----Last Day of Previous Month
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
LastDay_PreviousMonth
```

My code looks as follows but I the error I am seeing is about converting 0 to a date.

```
DECLARE @date DATE
SET @date = getdate()

SELECT dateadd(second,-1,dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

If anyone has any suggestions I would be very grateful for your guidance.

Comment: Please provide the complete error message

Comment: Aside: The best practice is to use `month` with `DateAdd` and `DateDiff` to specify the `datepart`. The worst practice is to use both `mm` and `m` in a single expression.

Comment: @Used_By_Already [Code: 102, SQL State: 42W04]  SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near 'datediff' on line 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your WHERE clause, you could use this condition:

```
DATEDIFF(month, [YourDateColumn], GETDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 36
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code looks good without any error, but you can use [`EOMONTH()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead.

However, the difference would be in return types your code would return date-time while `eomonth()` would return date only.

```
DECLARE @date DATE
SET @date = getdate()

SELECT EOMONTH(@date, -1)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but EOMONTH() doesn't appear to be a function that works in my database. I've checked the sybase documentation and it doesn't appear in there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TheGoat. . .  `EOMONTH()` is available with `SQL Server`.

Comment: Maybe so but I am using Sybase Transact-SQL??

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `between` and the job becomes far easier. Use less than the **first day of the current month** which accurately locates everything before that date (instead of last day of previous month). Subtract 3 years from that same date and use >= for the starting point.

```
Select *
From yourtables
where datecol >= dateadd (year,-3,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0) )
And datecol < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

Please don't use any solution that use 23:59:59 as the end of a day. It is not the end of a day and several data types now support sub-second time precision.

---

If you really cannot use zero in the date functions simply use the base date of '1900-01-01' instead

```
SELECT
  DATEADD(YEAR, -3, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), '1900-01-01'))
, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), '1900-01-01')
;
```

This should also work (it does [in this demo here](https://rextester.com/GWR37434)):

```
SELECT
  DATEADD(YEAR, -3, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
;
```

Comment: my system doesn't appear to like datediff with 0

Comment: Please provide the exact error messages. Also chheck the database type and version. The solution above is TSQL.