# Rolling list of dates in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

Similar to a question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719553/pulling-data-from-sybase-sql-database-using-rolling-window) but related to Sybase SQL, I am looking to get a list of dates for my where clause to filter a table in Netezza.

Currently, my where clause needs to be updated each time I run the query with manual dates, I wish to automate this to use the last 36 months of data but from the end of the previous month. So if today is 10/10/2018 I wish to go back 36 months from 30/09/2018.

My current Netezza where clause looks as follows:

```
WHERE

    table.DateCol BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2018-09-30'
```

I've found some examples [here](http://dwgeek.com/netezza-date-functions-examples.html/) about extracting the last day of the month and first day but I can't figure out how to concatenate them together to get a list of dates using 'BETWEEN' and 'AND'

```
--last_day(now() - interval'36 month') + interval '1 day'  
--last_day(now() - interval'1 month')
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
where t.datecol between last_day(current_date - interval '36 month') + interval '1 day' and
                        last_day(current_date - interval '1 month')
```